# Unity 5.4 Localization for Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build, compilation

I would like to localize the app names with Unity 5.4. I see a lot of tutorials but they are not work, these methods is deprecated in Unity 5.4.

I would like the following:
In english the app name would be  Hello
in Spanish       would be Hola   etc

How can I do it?
I tried to place `Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values`   values-es    etc  and `strings.xml` in all but none of them works. 
I get the following warning message every time:

OBSOLETE - Providing Android resources in `Assets/Plugins/Android/res` is deprecated, please move your resources to an Android Library. See "Building Plugins for Android" section of the Manual.
`UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()`

Comment: `See "Building Plugins for Android" section of the Manual. ` did you read this manual?

Comment: yes but i didn't find anything at that